# Want to access my baseurl and change the index page

Tags: php, codeigniter-url

I am using codeigniter and I want to change base url and index page. Like local `http://localhost/project/index.php/upload` to `www.upload.com/upload`..
where upload is a view i want to use it for my index page like
www.upload.com I enter and upload page will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Using .htacces:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ex.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```